# Inequality with 2 fixed variables

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a,b$ be two fixed positive reals, $x,y$ be two postives such that $x+y=a+b$. Find the minimum value of 
$$x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+y\sqrt{y^2+b^2}$$

My attempt: I guess that the min occurs when $x=b$ and $y=a$. Using Cauchy-Schwarz I've tried expressions like $(x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+y\sqrt{y^2+b^2})^2(\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}+\frac{y}{y^2+b^2})$, $(x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+y\sqrt{y^2+b^2})^2(\frac{1}{x(x^2+a^2)}+\frac{1}{y(y^2+b^2)})$, but with no progress.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Substitute $y=a+b-x$. Then this just a function of $x$. You can now differentiate and set that to zero. Probably messy, but the advice is free.

Answer (score 1):

As  marty cohen commented, get rid of $y$ replacing it y $y=a+b-x$. This leads to $$f(x)=x \sqrt{a^2+x^2}+(a+b-x)\sqrt{(a+b-x)^2+b^2} $$ The drivative "looks" simple $$f'(x)=\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}-\frac{(a+b-x)^2}{\sqrt{(a+b-x)^2+b^2}}-\sqrt{(a+b-x)^2+b^2}$$ Let us check a few values first (taking into account that $a$ and $b$ are positive) $$f'(a)=\frac 3 {\sqrt 2 }(a-b)$$ $$f'(b)=\frac{b^2-a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ So, except if $a=b$, these are not critical points.

What is making me afraid is that, by successive squaring, we arrive (tedious work, be sure) to a pentic equation in $x$ $$A+Bx+Cx^2+Dx^3+Ex^4+8x^5=0$$ where $$A=-3 a^5-11 a^4 b-15 a^3 b^2-9 a^2 b^3$$ $$B=14 a^4+32 a^3 b+24 a^2 b^2$$ $$C=-23 a^3-33 a^2 b-15 a b^2-9 b^3$$ $$D=24 a^2+32 a b+24 b^2$$ which does not show analytical solutions.

As  marty cohen commented, this looks to be a quite messy problem.

If we assume $b=a$, the pentic equation becomes $$f'(x)=-38 a^5+70 a^4 x-80 a^3 x^2+80 a^2 x^3-40 a x^4+8 x^5$$ and letting $x=az$ $$4 z^5-20 z^4+40 z^3-40 z^2+35 z-19=0$$ which has only one real root $z=1$. Under all these assumptions, for $x=a=b$, $f(a)=2 \sqrt{2} a^2$.

But we still need to prove that this is a minimum. Then (fun again), compute the second derivative still assuming $b=a$ and we finally get $f''(a)=\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}} >0$. So, this point is a minimum !!

And, if $x=a$, then $y=b$.

**Edit**

Let us set $b=ka$ and $x=az$; this makes $$-\left(9 k^3+15 k^2+11 k+3\right)+\left(24 k^2+32 k+14\right) z-\left(9 k^3+15
   k^2+33 k+23\right) z^2+8 \left(3 k^2+4 k+3\right) z^3-20 (k+1) z^4+8
   z^5=0$$

Trying with integer values of $k$, I got the following solutions for $z_k$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & z_k \\
 1 & 1.00000 \\
 2 & 1.60016 \\
 3 & 2.20155 \\
 4 & 2.80458 \\
 5 & 3.40892 \\
 6 & 4.01422 \\
 7 & 4.62018 \\
 8 & 5.22663 \\
 9 & 5.83344 \\
 10 & 6.44052 \\
 11 & 7.04780 \\
 12 & 7.65525
\end{array}
\right)$$

What is interesting is that it looks that $$z_k=1+0.604247 (k-1)\qquad \qquad (R^2=0.999999)$$ So, there are solutions for any value of $k$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I'm still wondering if there is a full solution for $a\neq b$ as well as a simpler one :)

Comment: @YiyiRao. Since it is not possible to solve a quintic polynomial (even with radicals), I do not think that there is any hope. I shall try something else and let you know.

Comment: Also, the Galois group of the quintic is $S_5$ in general (I checked for example that it is $S_5$ when $a=3$ and $b=4$).